# calculating length of stay with transfer dates in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am having a hard time figuring out how to calculate what I need in Power BI. The data I am looking at involves the length of stay in various programs. Some people transfer between programs and others do not. The way the transfer data is stored, I was able to extract it in the following format from SQL. The first 4 columns are from one table which is linked to a table with transfer data (last 3 columns). See below for sample data going in to Power BI.
[image: input data]

I need to calculate the length of stay for each person in each program, taking into account the transfer data. See below for the desired output.

[image: desired output]

If the person does not have a transfer, then the length of stay is (end date) - (start date). If the end date is null, then it is calculated based on the last day of the month (in this example, 7/31/2020).

If there are transfer/s, we need to calculate the length of stay in each program.
For person 234, they were in Program A from 5/15/2020 to 6/1/2020 when they transferred to B. Person 234 was in Program B from 6/1/2020 (transfer date from A to B) until 6/15/2020 (transfer date B to C). Then Person 234 was in Program C 6/15/2020 until 7/1/2020 (end date).

Please let me know if you have any ideas of how to get this calculation. I can use Power BI which will be my output, or I could edit the SQL query. Thank you for your help; I hope this post is clear enough!

Comment: How do you calculate the length of stay? You should add some calculations examples. Specially for person 234. I cant figure out which the correct logic process is.

Comment: I added narrative above explaining the length of stay calculation. Thank you for your help!